# Why won't my async call fire inside this Vue 3 component (using composition API)?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to make an async call to fetch data from my Fauna database. But I can't get the async call to fire.

Inside the `setup()` function I have `console.log("Setup is working");` and that works as expected. It shows on page load.

Then inside the `callApi` async function I have `console.log("callApi is working");`. That async function is called on a button click event. But when clicking the button nothing happens. The function is not fired and nothing prints to the console.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-5">
      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" @click="callApi">
        Call API
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="result-block-container">
      <div :class="['result-block', executed ? 'show' : '']">
        <h6 class="muted">Result</h6>
        {{ JSON.stringify(apiMessage, null, 2) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";
import { query as q, client } from "faunadb";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Api",
  setup() {
    console.log("Setup is working"); //<---- THIS PRINTS TO CONSOLE ON PAGE LOAD
    const callApi = async () => {
      console.log("callApi is working"); //<---- THIS DOES NOT PRINT TO CONSOLE ON BUTTON CLICK
      const apiMessage = null;
      const executed = false;
      const auth = inject("Auth");
      const accessToken = await Auth.getTokenSilently();
      try {
        const client = new Client({ secret: accessToken });
        const { Paginate, Documents, Collection, Lambda, Get, Var } = q;

        const data = await client.query(
          q.Map(
            Paginate(Documents(Collection("stores"))),
            Lambda(["storeRef"], Get(Var("storeRef")))
          )
        );

        console.log(data);
        apiMessage = data;
        executed = true;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        apiMessage = `Error: the server responded with '${e.response.status}: ${e.response.statusText}'`;
      }
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to `return` something from `setup()`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks that was it - want to add it as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### [Usage with Templates](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-templates)
>
> If setup returns an object, the properties on the object can be accessed in the component's template

You just need to return the properties you want available to your template

```js
return {
  callApi
}
```